# how to check the cells in data table contains values or not

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am having a data table.

In that table there are values only in some cells.

How can I check whether a particular cell contains values or not?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. cell.value property can be checked with null, if that's what you want.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Provide some code and you will for sure find somebody to help you.

Comment: string a = "select Break1_Start, Break1_End, Break2_Start, Break2_End, Break3_Star,Break3_End from Attendance_Register where Employee_ID='" + da.remEMP(ei) + "' and Date='"+ d +"' ";
            dt = da.getdetails(a);

Comment: i am havind the data table in 'dt'..

Comment: if (dt != null && ____________________)
{
 
}

HERE 'dt' is datatable.. IN 'dt' I GOT A DATATABLE..
THE ABOVE COMMAND SPECIFY THAT DATATABLE IS NOT NULL ,, 
AND INTHE DASH FIELD I NEED TI CHECK ONE PARTICULAR CELL IN THE DATA TABLE IS EMPTY OR NOT.
 
HOW CAN I DO THAT....

Answer (score 0):

Use 'IS NULL':

```
select *
from tableA
where row1 is null
```

You can also convert those empty cells to default values using ISNULL(row1, 'emptycell')

```
select isnull(row1, 'thiscellwasempty')
from tableA
```

If you need to check inside C# you can compare the cell value to System.DBNull.Value.

Comment: i want to check a row to find any cell is empty..how can i do that

Comment: Do you want the answer using C# or SQL Server? Do you know the name of the column or is it literally 'any cell'?

Comment: i got  the datatable ....i wnt to identify the empty cell in that datatable..and need ti insert value to only that empty cells..

Comment: Compare each cell to System.DBNull.Value and then set the cell value to whatever you like.

Comment: if (dt != null && ____________________)
{
 
}

HERE 'dt' is datatable.. IN 'dt' I GOT A DATATABLE..
THE ABOVE COMMAND SPECIFY THAT DATATABLE IS NOT NULL ,, 
AND INTHE DASH FIELD I NEED TI CHECK ONE PARTICULAR CELL IN THE DATA TABLE IS EMPTY OR NOT.
 
HOW CAN I DO THAT....

Answer (score 0):

try this to check all cells (VB.NET):

```
For Each drRow As DataRow In dtTable.Rows
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtTable.Columns.Count - 1
        If IsDBNull(drRow(i)) Or IsNothing(drRow(i)) Or IsEmpty(drRow(i)) Then
            MsgBox("DBNull, Nothing or Empty!")
        End If
    Next i
Next drRow
```

Comment: if (dt != null && ____________________)
{
 
}

HERE 'dt' is datatable.. IN 'dt' I GOT A DATATABLE..
THE ABOVE COMMAND SPECIFY THAT DATATABLE IS NOT NULL ,, 
AND INTHE DASH FIELD I NEED TI CHECK ONE PARTICULAR CELL IN THE DATA TABLE IS EMPTY OR NOT.
 
HOW CAN I DO THAT....

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ

```
bool bIsContainData = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(s => s.Field<string>
                                            ("YourField") != null && s.Field<string>
                                            ("YourField").Trim() != ""))
```